# Error installing Xamarin studio on Windows

Tags: windows, xamarin, installation, xamarin-studio

I'm trying to install Xamarin studio on Windows 10, but when i start the installer i receive this error by installer:

Startup task failed
Si sono verificati uno o più errori.
Exception type: System.AggregateException
Caratteri non validi nel percorso.
Exception type: System.ArgumentException
Full stack trace:
in Xamarin.Web.Installer.TasksManager.DetectComponents()
in Xamarin.Web.Installer.TasksManager.<>c__DisplayClass19_0.b__0(Object e)

I attach log:

```
[2017-03-06 13:16:20.522] [Debug] Setting registry key 'SOFTWARE\Xamarin\AnalyticsAsked' to '1'
[2017-03-06 13:16:20.530] [Debug] Setting registry key 'SOFTWARE\Xamarin\AnalyticsConsent' to '0'
[2017-03-06 13:16:20.541] [Debug] Setting registry key 'SOFTWARE\Xamarin\AnalyticsAsked' to '1'
[2017-03-06 13:16:20.552] [Debug] Setting registry key 'SOFTWARE\Xamarin\AnalyticsConsent' to '0'
[2017-03-06 13:16:20.564] [Info] Installation ID: 9eba69bd-64b5-455c-a69a-5896582e750b
[2017-03-06 13:16:20.574] [Info] Operating system: Windows 10 v10.0.14393 (Enterprise; Microsoft Windows 10 v10.0.14393 (Enterprise; 64-bit)), 64-bit
[2017-03-06 13:16:20.585] [Info] Installer product: Xamarin
[2017-03-06 13:16:20.596] [Info] Installer version: 4.0.0.57 stable (dcc7dd3690706e0d8a0e1f3b1fba64c5a7c78579 on 05/01/2017 10:08:05)
[2017-03-06 13:16:20.607] [Info] Status: in progress
[2017-03-06 13:16:20.618] [Debug] My location: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\B0C8D6C829BB2D63ACDE7E75A9A62618923C045C\WindowsInstaller.exe
[2017-03-06 13:16:20.826] [Debug] Setting registry key 'SOFTWARE\Xamarin\AnalyticsAsked' to '1'
[2017-03-06 13:16:20.837] [Debug] Setting registry key 'SOFTWARE\Xamarin\AnalyticsConsent' to '0'
[2017-03-06 13:16:21.046] [Info] Retrieving installation manifest.
[2017-03-06 13:16:21.057] [Info] Downloading from 'https://www.xamarin.com/installer_assets/v3/dcc7dd3690706e0d8a0e1f3b1fba64c5a7c78579/Windows/Universal/InstallationManifest.xml'.
[2017-03-06 13:16:21.068] [Debug] Setting download timeout for 'https://www.xamarin.com/installer_assets/v3/dcc7dd3690706e0d8a0e1f3b1fba64c5a7c78579/Windows/Universal/InstallationManifest.xml' to 60s
[2017-03-06 13:16:21.683] [Info] Downloading from 'https://www.xamarin.com/installer_assets/v3/Windows/Universal/InstallationManifest.xml'.
[2017-03-06 13:16:21.694] [Debug] Setting download timeout for 'https://www.xamarin.com/installer_assets/v3/Windows/Universal/InstallationManifest.xml' to 60s
[2017-03-06 13:16:22.206] [Info] Retrieving installation size manifest.
[2017-03-06 13:16:22.217] [Info] Downloading from 'https://www.xamarin.com/installer_assets/v3/Windows/Universal/InstallationSizes.xml'.
[2017-03-06 13:16:22.228] [Debug] Setting download timeout for 'https://www.xamarin.com/installer_assets/v3/Windows/Universal/InstallationSizes.xml' to 60s
[2017-03-06 13:16:22.536] [Exception] Failed to retrieve response for URL 'https://www.xamarin.com/installer_assets/v3/Windows/Universal/InstallationSizes.xml'
[2017-03-06 13:16:22.536] [Exception] System.Net.WebException: Errore del server remoto: (403) Non consentito.
[2017-03-06 13:16:22.536] [Exception] in System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
[2017-03-06 13:16:22.536] [Exception] in Xamarin.Components.Ide.Web.RequestHelper.GetResponse(Func`1 createRequest, Action`1 prepareRequest)
[2017-03-06 13:16:22.536] [Exception] in Xamarin.Web.Installer.Utilities.DownloadUrl(String url, Action`4 doDownload, Func`3 webExceptionHandler, Boolean noCache, Object state, Int32 timeout, Stream outputStream, String targetFileName)
[2017-03-06 13:16:22.547] [Exception] Failed to download resource from 'https://www.xamarin.com/installer_assets/v3/Windows/Universal/InstallationSizes.xml'
[2017-03-06 13:16:22.547] [Exception] System.Net.WebException: Errore del server remoto: (403) Non consentito.
[2017-03-06 13:16:22.547] [Exception] in System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
[2017-03-06 13:16:22.547] [Exception] in Xamarin.Components.Ide.Web.RequestHelper.GetResponse(Func`1 createRequest, Action`1 prepareRequest)
[2017-03-06 13:16:22.547] [Exception] in Xamarin.Web.Installer.Utilities.DownloadUrl(String url, Action`4 doDownload, Func`3 webExceptionHandler, Boolean noCache, Object state, Int32 timeout, Stream outputStream, String targetFileName)
[2017-03-06 13:16:22.547] [Exception] in Xamarin.Web.Installer.Utilities.GetManifest(String description, String resourceName, String resourceRelativeUrl, Boolean throwOnMissing, Boolean fineIfMissing, Boolean fallbackToEmbedded)
[2017-03-06 13:16:22.558] [Info] Determining list of software items to install.
[2017-03-06 13:16:22.573] [Debug] Processing update nodes from the manifest.
[2017-03-06 13:16:22.581] [Debug] Creating and initializing software item 'Java JDK'
[2017-03-06 13:16:22.686] [Debug] Creating and initializing software item 'Android SDK'
[2017-03-06 13:16:22.697] [Warning] Failed to compose local base path from 'Z:" ' and 'Xamarin\Universal'. Will use the default location (<USER_HOME>)
[2017-03-06 13:16:22.708] [Warning] System.ArgumentException: Caratteri non validi nel percorso.
[2017-03-06 13:16:22.708] [Warning] in System.IO.Path.CheckInvalidPathChars(String path, Boolean checkAdditional)
[2017-03-06 13:16:22.708] [Warning] in System.IO.Path.Combine(String path1, String path2)
[2017-03-06 13:16:22.708] [Warning] in Xamarin.Web.Installer.WindowsUtilitiesConfiguration.GetLocalBasePath(String productPathSuffix)
[2017-03-06 13:16:22.719] [Warning] Failed to compose local base path from 'Z:" ' and 'Xamarin\MonoForAndroid'. Will use the default location (<USER_HOME>)
[2017-03-06 13:16:22.730] [Warning] System.ArgumentException: Caratteri non validi nel percorso.
[2017-03-06 13:16:22.730] [Warning] in System.IO.Path.CheckInvalidPathChars(String path, Boolean checkAdditional)
[2017-03-06 13:16:22.730] [Warning] in System.IO.Path.Combine(String path1, String path2)
[2017-03-06 13:16:22.730] [Warning] in Xamarin.Web.Installer.WindowsUtilitiesConfiguration.GetLocalBasePath(String productPathSuffix)
[2017-03-06 13:16:22.741] [Debug] Creating and initializing software item 'Microsoft® MSBuild Tools 2015'
[2017-03-06 13:16:22.752] [Debug] Creating and initializing software item 'Xamarin'
[2017-03-06 13:16:22.763] [Debug] Creating and initializing software item 'Intel® HAXM'
[2017-03-06 13:16:22.774] [Debug] Creating and initializing software item 'Xamarin Profiler'
[2017-03-06 13:16:22.785] [Debug] Creating and initializing software item 'Xamarin Workbooks & Inspector'
[2017-03-06 13:16:22.796] [Debug] Creating and initializing software item 'Remoted iOS Simulator'
[2017-03-06 13:16:22.807] [Debug] Detecting software item 'Java JDK'
[2017-03-06 13:16:22.808] [Info] Checking whether JDK needs to be installed.
[2017-03-06 13:16:22.808] [Debug] Attempting to read registry subkey 'SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\JavaSoft\Java Development Kit', value 'CurrentVersion'
[2017-03-06 13:16:22.809] [Debug] Attempting to read registry subkey 'SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\JavaSoft\Java Development Kit\1.8', value 'JavaHome'
[2017-03-06 13:16:22.809] [Debug] Attempting to read registry subkey 'SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\JavaSoft\Java Development Kit\1.8', value 'JavaHome'
[2017-03-06 13:16:22.810] [Info] Required JDK already installed alongside incompatible version 1.8
[2017-03-06 13:16:22.810] [Info] Status: successful
[2017-03-06 13:16:22.811] [Info] Component 'Java JDK' v. 1.8.0 present
[2017-03-06 13:16:22.811] [Info] Software item 'Java JDK': up to date
[2017-03-06 13:16:22.811] [Debug] Detecting software item 'Android SDK'
[2017-03-06 13:16:22.812] [Info] Checking if Android SDK needs to be updated/installed
[2017-03-06 13:16:22.812] [Info] Using default samples:
[2017-03-06 13:16:22.813] [Info] Status: failed.
[2017-03-06 13:16:22.813] [Exception] Failed to detect component 'Android SDK'
[2017-03-06 13:16:22.813] [Exception] System.ArgumentException: Caratteri non validi nel percorso.
[2017-03-06 13:16:22.813] [Exception] in System.IO.Path.CheckInvalidPathChars(String path, Boolean checkAdditional)
[2017-03-06 13:16:22.813] [Exception] in System.IO.Path.Combine(String path1, String path2)
[2017-03-06 13:16:22.813] [Exception] in Xamarin.Installer.AndroidSDK.AndroidSDKInstaller..ctor(IHelpers helpers, Boolean xamarinMode)
[2017-03-06 13:16:22.813] [Exception] in Xamarin.Web.Installer.Installer.AndroidSoftwareItem.InitInstaller()
[2017-03-06 13:16:22.813] [Exception] in Xamarin.Web.Installer.Installer.AndroidSoftwareItem.NeedsUpdate()
[2017-03-06 13:16:22.813] [Exception] in Xamarin.Web.Installer.TasksManager.ComponentDetector(ISoftwareItem si)
[2017-03-06 13:16:22.814] [Exception] Detection failed for task Android SDK.
[2017-03-06 13:16:22.814] [Exception] System.ArgumentException: Caratteri non validi nel percorso.
[2017-03-06 13:16:22.814] [Exception] in Xamarin.Web.Installer.TasksManager.DetectComponents()
[2017-03-06 13:16:23.520] [Exception] Startup task failed
[2017-03-06 13:16:23.520] [Exception] System.AggregateException: Si sono verificati uno o più errori. ---> System.ArgumentException: Caratteri non validi nel percorso.
[2017-03-06 13:16:23.520] [Exception] in Xamarin.Web.Installer.TasksManager.DetectComponents()
[2017-03-06 13:16:23.520] [Exception] in Xamarin.Web.Installer.TasksManager.<>c__DisplayClass19_0.<Start>b__0(Object e)
[2017-03-06 13:16:23.520] [Exception] --- Fine della traccia dello stack dell'eccezione interna ---
[2017-03-06 13:16:23.520] [Exception] ---> (Eccezione interna 0) System.ArgumentException: Caratteri non validi nel percorso.
[2017-03-06 13:16:23.520] [Exception] in Xamarin.Web.Installer.TasksManager.DetectComponents()
[2017-03-06 13:16:23.520] [Exception] in Xamarin.Web.Installer.TasksManager.<>c__DisplayClass19_0.<Start>b__0(Object e)<---
[2017-03-06 13:16:23.520] [Debug] Showing manual installation window because of error
```

I used this guide to manual install the software but it doesn't work.

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/installation/windows/manual_installation/#Xamarin_Studio_Installation

Where is my problem?

Comment: Although it does not answer your question, I would not recommend to install Xamarin Studio on Windows at all anymore. It retires and will no longer be supported. Use Visual Studio (free Community Edition for example) instead!

Comment: I have VS enterprise, but i like Xamarin Studio to work with android. But since today i think i will start to work with VS. Thanks :)